# Is it usefull to use onSaveInstantState if I use SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, save, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I have a question about performances. Is it usefull to use onSaveInstantState if I use SharedPreferences ?

I mean, if it worth to make a condition to test:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {
    // load with on save instant state
}

else {
    // load with shared preferences
}
```

or I should always load the datas from SharedPreferences ?

Thank you

Comment: what is the requirement?? what type of data you are going to store?? Is that data need to be persistent even after app is killed & reopened again??

Comment: It's a collection of objects (I use gson to store in sharedPreferences) and the data needs to be persistant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need data to be persistent across any cases, then go for **SQLite**.

Comment: That's why I wonder if Sqlite would be faster or slower than Sharedpreference + gson

Comment: SQLite will help more on the data manipulation. If you need to query data for some condition, SQLite will help but nothing can be done on SharedPreferences.

Comment: The problem is I don't need to edit those dates, only read them

Comment: Thanks, I think I will stay on Sharedpreference

Comment: Only one thing, SharedPreference data can get erased.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, it is still useful, there are a lot of things that you can't save in the SharedPrefrences dictionary like Lists, Maps or any other custom object.

You should plan on saving information on your [SharedPrefrences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) if you want the data to be persisted through application uses (after your application has been destroyed), and save information onSaveInstanceState bundle if you want to persist data through [configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) (rotation, font-size change, language change).

Comment: Actually, it's a collection of objects so I use Gson to save those datas. By the way, is it worth to use Gson and SharedPreferences (it's a small collection max: 100 items)  or use SQLite ?

Comment: That would be another question, but I would deserialize the JSON and save the objects in an SQLite database.